# TypeError: marching_cubes() got unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, scikit-image

I have imported the measure module from the `skimage` package. I want to execute the measure function marching cubes. Here is the function call I make:

```
from skimage import measure

stuff = measure.marching_cubes(volume = p, 
              level = threshold, step_size = 1, 
              allow_degenerate = True)
```

This function call throws a traceback error saying `TypeError: marching_cubes() got an unexpected keyword argument 'step_size'`.  However, `measure.marching_cubes()` function does accept a `step_size` argument ([see docs](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.marching_cubes)).

If I comment out the `step_size` and `allow_degenerate` parameters (they have default values), then the call works correctly, but `marching_cubes` only returns 2 parameters (vert and faces) when I expect it to return 4 parameters (verts, faces, normals, and values).

What am I doing wrong, and what should I do to get the expected behavior from `measure.marching_cubes()`?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: I use Python 2.7.12

Comment: @YohanSumathipala Did you try upgrading the version of `skimage` library? See the answer below.. :)

Comment: @YohanSumathipala Peter was actually referring to the version of `skimage` not `python` ....

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is a version problem with the `skimage` library you are using.

The [documentation link](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.marching_cubes) provided by you is for skimage version 0.14. In this version the parameter `'step_size'` is present.

However in skimage version 0.12, `measure.marching_cubes()` function is also present but with only 4 parameters excluding `step_size`. I suspect you have might be using version 0.12.

You have also stated that *'`marching_cubes` only returns 2 parameters (`vert` and `faces`) when I expect it to return 4 parameters (`verts`, `faces`, `normal`, and `values`).'* In version 0.12 the function returns only two parameters. Hence I strongly suspect you are using an older version of `skimage`

I was able to figure this out by looking up at the [documentation for version 0.12](http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.12.x/api/skimage.measure.html?highlight=measure#skimage.measure.marching_cubes)

### Solution:

Try upgrading the `skimage` library to the latest version (currently v0.14) and hopefully it should work.

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

in the newer version of skimage (it gets updated while updating scikit-image,) step_size parameter is present. But the old method is replaced by two methods; marching_cubes_lewiner and marching_cubes_classic. The method marching_cubes_lewiner takes step_size parameter. Please try it after updating.